# Is it possible to ignore json_parse_exception during reindex in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I am trying to `reindex` an existing index into a new one with different analyzers.

```
es.reindex({
        "source": {"index": "index"},
        "dest": {"index": settings.ES_INDEX}
    }, wait_for_completion=True, request_timeout=36000)
```

The data is pretty big, more than 30 000 000 documents.
But after 20 hours of working I got an exception

> "failures":[{"index":"index_ru","type":"page","id":"rLKzd2wBwqP9nlBSLbNG","cause":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [raw_html]","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x20\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@130873db; line: 1, column: 769928]"}},"status":400}]}

Only 30% of the documents were processed.
Apparently, there is a problem with encoding in one of the documents. Because of that reindex process was stopped... Is there a way to ignore such problems? I don't care if a few documents won't be reindexed.

Thank you.

Comment: try do the bulk upload with smaller chunks, or retry on failed chucks

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: i don't think that's possible with `reindex` api: see `response body -> failures` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html